# Running a command with a dynamic list of arguments

Tags: powershell-core

I'm trying to write a wrapper for Get-PSSession that simplifies SSH remoting for me, but I'm running into an issue where it appears that powershell core does not parse switches in arguments passed to the '&' operator:

```
$cmd, $args = "dir", ("-Depth", "1", "c:", "d:")
& $cmd $args

$cmd, $args = "dir", @("-Depth", "1", "c:", "d:")
& $cmd $args

$cmd, $args = "dir", ("-Depth:1", "C:", "D:")
& $cmd $args
```

all complain

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\...\-Depth' because it does not exist.
```

The only way to do this seems to be with the unsafe-feeling

```
Invoke-Expression "& $cmd $args"
```

but now I've got to deal with ensuring that all parameters are properly escaped/quoted/etc.

In my final use case, the number of arguments is variable:

```
if ($KeyFilePath) {
    $arglist += ("-KeyFilePath", $KeyFilePath)
}
```

etc

Is there some better way to do this? Is there a way to ensure that any user-supplied parameters get properly quoted/escaped such that a malicious user can't just bypass them by adding their own escape/quote character? Is there a way to use a map/hash?

Answer (score 0):

Use the splat operator `@` as `@args`.

Your wrapper function will look like

```bsh
function Invoke-MyWrappedCommand {
  & /usr/bin/wrappedcommand -MyCustomArg1 Value @args
}
```

You can then alias a shorthand:

```bsh
set-alias wrappedcommand invoke-mywrappedcommand
```

Use like a regular command:

```bsh
PS> wrappedcommand -myarg2 value2
```

And the final command will launch `/usr/bin/wrappedcommand -MyCustomArg1 Value -myarg2 value2`

This is further described in the PowerShell documentation [about_Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6#splatting-command-parameters).